# Tensorflow Generator with multiple inputs reading multiple files causes the Kernel to crash

Tags: python, tensorflow, generator

I am new to StackOverflow, as well as Generators, so there might be some poor formatting choices here. I'm working on a machine learning project, and I found in my reading that defining a generator would be beneficial for my data processing since my dataset is very large and there is a lot of preprocessing I need to do. My model takes two inputs, each a matrix of shape (5,480,480,3) and outputs one of 9 classes. My dataset is a bunch of npz files that contain 20 (5,480,480,3) matrices. My generator needs to call a function called `get_sub_images`(which I have sufficiently debugged and identified as not the problem) that takes one of these matrices and turns it into to matrices of the same type (This function identifies objects with a bounding box using YOLO and splits each of the 5 images into object and background images). This generator works fine if I make my batch size one file, but the Kernel crashes when I increase the batch size to 2, and I'm not sure why. What could be causing this? I'm thinking it either has to do with a bug in my loop structure, or the time spent on my preprocessing functions (if that is a thing that can cause problems for generators).

I've attached my relevant pieces of code below. First is my generator function.

```
def tf_data_generator(file_list, batch_size = 1):
i = 0
while True:
    if i*batch_size >= len(file_list):
        print("\nShuffling and Restarting...")
        i = 0
        np.random.shuffle(file_list)
    else:
        file_chunk = file_list[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size] 
        print("\nTraining Files: ", file_chunk)
        data = [[],[]]
        labels = []
        
        for fil in file_chunk:
            with np.load(fil) as dat:
                training_data_images = dat['data']
                training_data_labels = dat['labels']


            to_shuffle = list(zip(training_data_images, training_data_labels))
            np.random.shuffle(to_shuffle)
            training_data_images, training_data_labels = zip(*to_shuffle)

            train_objects = []
            train_background = []
            for k in range(len(training_data_images)):
                train_objects.append([])
                train_background.append([])
                for j in range(5):
                    temp1,temp2 = get_sub_images(training_data_images[k][j])
                    train_objects[k].append(temp1)
                    train_background[k].append(temp2)

            X_train = [reshape_custom_X(np.array(train_objects)), reshape_custom_X(np.array(train_background))]
            y_train = reshape_custom_y(np.array(training_data_labels))
            
            for x in range(X_train[0].shape[0]):
                data[0].append(X_train[0][x])
                data[1].append(X_train[1][x])
                labels.append(y_train[x])
            
            
        yield (np.array(data[0]), np.array(data[1])), labels
        i = i + 1
```

And here is my training calls. Changing `batch_size = 2` causes my Kernel to crash.

```
epochs = 1
batch_size = 1
file_names = glob.glob("Data\\**\*.npz", recursive=True)
np.random.shuffle(file_names)
train_file_names = file_names[0:int(len(file_names)*0.7)]
validation_file_names = file_names[int(len(file_names)*0.7):]

print(len(train_file_names), len(validation_file_names))
print(train_file_names, "\n", validation_file_names)


train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(tf_data_generator, args = [train_file_names, batch_size], 
                                              output_shapes = (((None,5,416,416,3), (None,5,416,416,3)),(None,9)),
                                              output_types = ((tf.float32, tf.float32), tf.float32))

validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(tf_data_generator, args = [validation_file_names, batch_size],
                                              output_shapes = (((None,5,416,416,3), (None,5,416,416,3)),(None,9)),
                                              output_types = ((tf.float32, tf.float32), tf.float32))


steps_per_epoch = np.int(np.ceil(len(train_file_names)/batch_size))
validation_steps = np.int(np.ceil(len(validation_file_names)/batch_size))
print("steps_per_epoch = ", steps_per_epoch)
print("validation_steps = ", validation_steps)

model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data = validation_dataset, steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
         validation_steps = validation_steps, epochs = epochs)
```

Last, here are some relevant bits about my model, in case they matter. I've included my compile statement as well as my first and last layers.

```
input1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(5, 416, 416, 3))
input2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(5, 416, 416, 3))
out = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(out)

model = Model(inputs=[x1.input,x2.input], outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Thanks for the help.